# Rails Bootstrap 4 bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I have experienced a small bug using Bootstrap in my Rails application. If you go to the page using a cellphone or resizing the window to use the collapsed menu, it works corretly. But, when you go to another page (About or Contact) and use the collapsed menu, open it and try to close it, it remains open.

https://jgprod.herokuapp.com/home

Have you experienced this before? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing the gem of bootstrap in my rails app!